# The bottom content jumps up when browser is refreshed or any links are clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am developing a [Website](http://jfcars.cdgbrand.com/)(PHP/Wordpress) which has a full screen background image. I am always having issues with background images where I am giving the height calculating the height of the screen/windows that the users views, my [Jquery Code](http://pastebin.com/HbkAbdXY). It takes time for it to load and you can see the bottom div when you click refresh in the browser or click any links. Can I use any page transitions for these not spinners or loading bar something that I can fade in or slider up or down when the page loads or refreshes or is there something else I should be doing. How to hide all these loading issues from the user ?

Comment: add a page for your project so we can see what you want

Comment: There is an entire website in the link so what do you mean when you say add a page ?

Comment: Just a suggestion, but have you tried setting the full screen background container's height to be 100% of the viewport? like div {height: 100vh; }

Comment: I did try but I don't know it did not work so i choose to find the height by JQuery. Is that not good ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your WP Theme Header put start a `<div>` wrap:

```
<div class="pageLoad">
```

And you can end it in your WP Theme Footer

```
</div>
```

You can use [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/) spinner as your loader. In the WP Theme Header after the pageLoad div add the spinner

```
<div class="buffer">
  <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i>
</div>
```

Create another `<div>` after the spinner, again it will start in your WP Theme Header and end in your WP Footer (or wherever you want to load)

```
<div class="body">

<!-- put rest of page content, photos, etc here -->

</div>
```

Then for the jQuery, you will count all the images and once they are done being loaded, it will hide the spinner and show the content:

```
var imgs = $(".pageLoad img")
var count = imgs.length;

$('.body').hide();

imgs.load(function() {
  count--;
  if (!count) {
        $('.body').show();
      $('.buffer').hide();
   }
}).filter(function() {
  return this.complete;
}).load();
```

**[jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/c2cwvgys/2/)**

You will have to test it with the background images but this should be enough for you to get started.

Comment: Thank You very much for a detailed explanation for an inexperienced like me. I do not want to use spinner or loading images but you gave me an idea of how to use transitions like fade or something  so that issue is hidden. I will try and let you know soon.